# How to make product grid in frontend in custom module magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, grid, frontend

I have created brand page to display details with associated product list.

I want to show that product list in grid same as admin.

Can it be possible to show grid in frontend same like backend ?

Comment: It is preferred to use Repositories. Example of block with ProductList can be found here: https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-service-contract-client/Block/ProductList.php

Comment: @ Dharmendra yes its possible .

Comment: @ Manish Goswami how can i do this ?

Comment: @DharmendraJadav Were you able to achieve this?

Comment: @ManishGoswami How can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you know about **MVVC & CURD in magento 2**.
You can achieve this by **Helper & View**, In view(phtml) you can write below code, to display you product.

```
//view 
$productHelper = $this->helper('<ext>\<module>\Helper\Product');
$productlist = $productHelper->getProductData();
foreach ($productlist as $product) {
$product_name = $product['name'];
//your grid listing code
}
```

In helper file you can write below code

```
//Helper Code 
Public function getProductData(){
            $products = $this->_objectManager->create(
               'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'
           )->load();
           //Your collection code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , but you change its backend-css files for store view page.First you look where is your store view css and you change the classes of it like as admin panel classes and you also changes backend-php files.